# how to include a ListView into a navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to include a listView into the navigation drawer but when I launch the application the listView doesn't appear into the drawer but in the main interface I can't find the problem please help me!

Java code :

```
    package com.example.anb_calculator;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;



    public class HomeFinanceActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    ListView liste = null;




   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_finance);

    // l'ajout du navigation drawer
     drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
     drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,               R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
     drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
     drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); 
     drawerToggle.syncState();


        //*************************/
    String[] values = new String[] { "Overview","Car Finance","Home Finance","Personal Finance"};
     liste = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
     List<String> exemple = new ArrayList<String>();
     exemple.add("Overview");
     exemple.add("Home Finance");
     exemple.add("Car Finance");
     exemple.add("Personal Finance");
     exemple.add("Credit Cards");

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, exemple);
     liste.setAdapter(adapter);
     //liste.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_finance, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
if(android.R.id.home == item.getItemId()) {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT) == false) {
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

    }
    else {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    }
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

 }
```

XML code :

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/white"
   >

   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.example.anb_calculator.HomeFinanceActivity" 
    android:background="@drawable/planplan">


   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/home_finance" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:text="@string/home_finance"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small_padding"
    android:gravity="center"
   android:textColor="@color/black"
   android:textStyle="bold"
  android:textSize="@dimen/large_size"

   />
 </RelativeLayout>
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:text="This is a navigation drawer"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    />

    <ListView
          android:id="@+id/listView"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"

          >
   </ListView>


     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [**documentation**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) of the `DrawerLayout` contains the solution to your problem:

> To use a DrawerLayout, position your primary content view as the first
>   child with a width and height of match_parent. Add drawers as child
>   views after the main content view and set the layout_gravity
>   appropriately. Drawers commonly use match_parent for height with a
>   fixed width.

So any child `View` of the `DrawerLayout` beyond the first one is interpreted as a drawer. `layout_gravity` determines the position of the `drawer` and from which direction they are swiped in.

So your problems are:

1. You have more than 2 children in the `DrawerLayout` (Don't know if you want that, would create more than one drawer).
2. You have not set the `layout_gravity` accordingly.

---

To fix it you just have to fix your layout! Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlFragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Content goes here!!!!!!1 -->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/lvDrawer"
              android:layout_width="240dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="start"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The only really important part here is that the `layout_gravity` of the `ListView` is set to `start`. This means you can swipe in the `ListView` from the left.

Answer (score -1):

You have to put your ListView in your DrawerLayout :

```
drawerLayout.addView(liste);
```

Say if it works :)

Comment: That is not the problem. Why would you have to add it again if it already is part of the `ViewGroup`? Makes no sense... See my answer for an actual solution.